# Web Engine in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebengine

I have installed the new community version of Qt 5.8 using the Windows installer. Kits for mingw MSVC++ 2013. I have the compilers for msvc++ 2013. I have checked the webengine option too.

I was looking to make a simple browser in qt webengine and I get the error

> error: Unknown module(s) in QT: webenginewidgets

I have used

```
QT += webenginewidgets
```

in the pro file and, run qmake and I'm still stuck with the same issue.

I am little bit confused since I cannot find anything that could help me anywhere.

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Should I install something else to get webengine or should I download the source and compile it? If so, how?

What is the simplest way to use webengine in Qt?

Comment: Are you sure that you are using msvc2013 Qt build at the moment? ```webenginewidgets``` module seems is not available for MinGW https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-44108

Comment: yes .. i checked the folder and cannot find any thing related to weengine in the qt msvc++ folder too

Comment: At the moment I have Qt 5.8.0 msvc2015 build installed on Windows and ```webenginewidgets``` module exists there

Comment: *using the window installer .Kits for mingw MSVC++ 2013* MinGW and MSVC are different compiler toolchains. Which Qt did you actually install? Since Chromium cannot be built with MinGW Qt/MinGW does not include WebEngine. If you installed both make sure you select the correct Kit when compiling your program.

Comment: Do we need to install MsVC++ 2015 to run webenginewidgets  any way downloading that

Comment: I was using Qt 5.8 MSVC++ 2013 compiler 
I used QT 5.8 MSVC++ 2015 and every thing is fixed

Answer (score 3):

I believe the new chromium no longer support the 2013 compiler and thus Qt also don't support 2013 compiler so download the 2015 MSVC compiler install it and use the 2015 binaries Kit for Qt 5.8 and every thing works just  fine ..

Comment: Now Needs MSVC++ 2017

Answer (score -1):

ReInstall Qt Creator and Make sure you Checked QtWebEngine at that time