# Unknown module(s) in QT: webengine webenginewidgets

Tags: qt, window, qt-creator

I want to compile a project that is done. However, I have some issues which make me impossible to compile it. My computer is windows 8.1

version of qt

[image]

Could someone help me, please?? I add some screen captures to help you.[error that appears when I compile the project

[image]

errors in main.cpp

[image]

screen that appears when I open the project

[image]

Comment: Did you add to your `makefile` `QT += webengine`?

Comment: read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42324169/web-engine-in-qt: *Now Needs MSVC++ 2017*